# Show in php how many 502 errors the server has

Tags: php, nginx

I want to show using php how many 502 errors does the server(nginx) have in the last 24 hours. I couldn't find a simple way to do it
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single way to do this. For a better solution, you could proxy your server only accepting requests from the local IP address. Something like this could work (not tested)

The simple solution:

```
grep '502' access.log | wc -l
```

The complex solution:

```
http {
  upstream error_logger {
    server 127.0.0.1:80
  }
}
server {
  error_page 502 /502.html
  location / {
   # all your config here
  }
  location /502.html {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://error_logger/502.php;
  }
}
```

The script (502.php);

```
  <?php
  if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') die();
  // do the logging here
```

Answer (score 1):

You could:

**Use PHP to parse your nginx log**
This would look something like:

```
$logfile = @file('/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

This would get you an array consisting of each line of the log file. You could then search for '502' using regular expressions. Keep in mind that web server log files can typically be quite large.

Alternatively, you could use a (better) scripting language like python or perl to perform this task for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat access-com.your-project.log | cut -d '"' -f3 | cut -d ' ' -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```